# How to convert grayscale image to rgb with full colors?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I'm trying to convert a grayscale image to rgb image . I searched the net and found this code:

```
rgbImage = repmat(grayImage,[1 1 3]);
rgbImage = cat(3,grayImage,grayImage,grayImage);
```

but what this does is only give the image in gray-scale with 3-D matrix.
I want to have a way that i can convert it into true color image.

Comment: How do you convert from grey to colour? You need to specify a colouring criterion. You don't have colur information in the grey image

Comment: This is not a real question, or shows a total lack of any background knowledge in the field.

Comment: First, use the `uncrop` function to get all the missing data back magically, get some reflection off a street lamp...

Comment: Do you simply want a red-tinted version of your grayscale image (or blue or green)? RGB is true color and that includes grays.

Comment: @Dogbert Look at the accepted answer, thats called good participation.

Comment: I did. I upvoted it too. Normally I would post such an answer, but it feels analogous to asking why dividing by zero in a programming language produces an error, and not considering basic arithmetic and that such an operation makes no sense there either. I answer this question once a semester as TA, and I don't get how people can assume such an operation makes sense. As for `uncrop`, that's a sci-fi joke, but a question I ask too (ie: is it possible). The information is not there to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **impossible** to directly recover a colour image from the grey scale version of it. As correctly said by @Luis Mendo in the comments, the needed information are not physically stored there.

What you can do is try to come up with a mapping between intensity level and colour, then play around with interpolation. This however will not produce a good result, but just some colour mapping information that may be very far from what you want.

If you have another colour image and you want to fit its colours to your grey scale image, you may want to have a look at: http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2012/11/25/converting-images-from-grayscale-to-color/ .
In particular the function that is there cited can be found here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8214-gray-image-to-color-image-conversion#comments.

Bare in mind that this will be slow and will not produce a great result, however I don't think you can do much more.

Answer (score 2):

yes it's impossible to directly convert gray scale image to rgb..but it is possible to add features or show something like an edge detected on gray scale image in rgb by adding it..if you want you can use this..

```
rgb = zeros([size(I_temp) 3]);

rgb(:,:,1) = im2double(rr);

rgb(:,:,2) = im2double(rg)+.05*double(I_temp) ;

rgb(:,:,3) = im2double(rb);
```

where rr,rg,rb are an rgb base image..