# Convert (previously RGB converted to)grayscale MAT back to RGB

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I want a camera captured image in android to be equlaized using histogram equalization.For this i converted bitmap o MAT, MAT to grayscale, perform equalizeHist on grayscale matrix. (Code works fine till here) and then i want image back in RGB. Any methods i can perform to get equalized matrix in RGB?
Here is the code

```
public Bitmap processing(Bitmap newImage) {
 Mat rgb = new Mat (newImage.getHeight(), 
newImage.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(4));
Mat gry = new Mat   (newImage.getHeight(),newImage.getWidth(),
CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(4));
              Utils.bitmapToMat(newImage, rgb);
              Imgproc.cvtColor(rgb, gry, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
              //Imgproc.equalizeHist(gry, gry);
              Imgproc.cvtColor(gry, rgb, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA);
              Utils.matToBitmap(rgb, newImage);
            return newImage;
          }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me whether this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833683/how-to-convert-grayscale-image-to-rgb-with-full-colors?rq=1

Comment: you can use the equalizeHist for each channel (r,g,b) - then you don't have to do it on the blackwhite image, but on your colored image

Comment: How do you do that? @martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [split](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#split), make some treatment and [merge](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#merge) color channels.

Note that result may look strange. Probably you would try to convert RGB to some other color model (like HSL), equalize brightness (`L` here) channel and convert back to RGB

Comment: Like you said, I converted rgb to YCBCR and performed equalization on Y channel, but the results don't make picture look better.
My goal is to overlay a captured image with another image and then perform equalization on image to make it look like one

Comment: How is equalization related to the likeness of images?

Comment: It will equalize the image to a balanced color one, is there any other better way to achieve this goal?
BTW i performed HSV equalization
Thankyou for the idea